# Not getting the notification from NotificationCompat.Builder

Tags: android-notifications

i want to generate a notification bar showing the progress via builder method but i dont know where i am going wrong.if anyone who can tell me where i am wrong and help me i will  be thankful.....

```
public class DownloadReceiver extends ResultReceiver{
    private final static String TAG = "DownloadReceiver"; 
    public Context context;
    public DownloadReceiver(Handler handler,Context context) {
        super(handler);
        this.context = context;
        Log.d(TAG,handler.getLooper().getThread().getName());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {
        super.onReceiveResult(resultCode, resultData);
        Log.d(TAG,"in download receiver");

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Service.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://www.android.com"));
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notifyIntent, 0);

    if(resultCode == DownloadService.COMPLETED){
            Log.d(TAG,resultCode + "");
            Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                                          .setProgress(100, 20, false)
                                          .addAction(R.drawable.ic_action_search, "title", pendingIntent)
                                          .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
    //      notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
            //      notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, "contentTitle", "contentText", pendingIntent);
            notificationManager.notify(50, notificationBuilder.build());
        }else if(resultCode == DownloadService.ALLCOMPLETED){

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I just had to deal with this just now, the solution for me was that you have to add a notification image

`.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.launcher)`

otherwise it won't show anything. The old notification method didn't require you to set this yourself, as it would default to the app's icon.